Finding $\lim_{\,n\to\infty} \, \sum_{k=n}^{3n} \binom{k-1}{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{k-n}$
The problem is to find the following limit:
$$\lim_{\,n\to\infty} \, \sum_{k=n}^{3n} \binom{k-1}{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{k-n}$$
I know it has something to do with CLT but I can't quite figure it out. I know that
$$
\sum_{k=n}^{3n} \binom{k-1}{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{k-n}= \quad
\sum_{k=n}^{3n} \frac{n}{k}\binom{k}{n}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{k-n} = 
\quad
\sum_{k=n}^{3n} P(S_k = n) \cdot\frac{n}{k}
$$
where $S_k \sim B(k, \frac{1}{3})$. However, I don't really see how it helps. I'd appreciate any hints.

Note that if $X \sim \mathrm{NB}(1/3, n)$, where $X$ counts the number of trials required to see $n$ successes (each with probability $p = 1/3$), then each term in your sum is the pmf of $X$.  In other words,
$$\sum_{k=n}^{3n}\binom{k-1}{n-1}(1/3)^n(2/3)^{k-n} = P(n \le X \le 3n).$$
Since $EX = n/p = 3n$ and $\text{Var}(X) = n(1-p)/p^2 = 6n$, we have
$$\sum_{k=n}^{3n}\binom{k-1}{n-1}(1/3)^n(2/3)^{k-n} \approx P\left(\frac{n - 3n}{\sqrt{6n}} \le Z \le \frac{3n - 3n}{\sqrt{6n}} \right),$$
for large $n$, by the Central Limit Theorem.  From there, you can compute the probability.

This distribution just left my mind. Thanks!

Considering there are, like, eight different forms of the pmf, it would seem easy for that to happen! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Alternative_formulations

For the record, I realized as I was waking up this morning that since this form of negative binomial distribution is defined only for $x \ge n$, we can just look at $P(X\le 3n)$, and save ourselves the trouble of figuring out what happens to $-2\sqrt{n}/\sqrt{6}$ as $n$ increases :).
